# How would I add haze?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

[image]

How would I add a haze, just at the bottom of a liquid? The solids for lack of a better word, in Miso soup settles at the bottom and creates a haze. I would like to create that to make this look as realistic as possible.

Comment: For this still image? Probably with Volumetric node?

Comment: You should mention if this is for Cycles or Eevee.

Comment: https://youtu.be/fdWUjEMzDhg?t=257

Comment: @JustMe ... I mean if you don't plan an animated liquid simulation - so Volume shader can be enough :) If you plan anim there is only one option to use FlipFluid addon that simulates particles like a sand, that can gives you probably similar result. Miso soup lover ... I'm going make one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

[image]

You can Play with Multiply (Math) node Value to make it more dense or soft ...

[image]